# Testing, analyzing, preventing, and handling mass or spam requests to ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, security

I am developing a web API in ASP.NET that does some image processing. Essentially the user application will make get requests with a few arguments i.e an image, quality, text to draw on it, size, etc.

My concern is that I do not know exactly how fast these requests are going to come in. If I spam refresh on a get request for long enough, I see the memory starting to slowly increase until it hits 1G and then finally throws an OutOfMemory exception. Strangely enough, sometimes before hitting the OOM, I get a ArgumentException (even though I am using a valid request that works otherwise).

My questions are broad and as follows:

1) Is there a good tool to test this sort of mass request? I'd like to be able to spam my server so I can consistently analyze and troubleshoot any problems that arise. I havn't found anything and have just been clicking / pressing enter on the browser manually..

2) Is there a tool you'd recommend to analyze what specific processes in my program are causing this memory issue? If the Diagnostic Tools in VS are good enough, can you offer some guidance as to what I should be looking for? I.e investigating the call stack, memory profiling, etc..

3) Perhaps none of the above questions are even necessary if this one can be answered: Can these sort of requests be prevented? Maybe my API can ensure that they are only processed at a speed that can be handled (at the expense of user image load time).. I know that catching the exceptions alone isn't going to be enough, so is there something that ASP.NET provides for this sort of mass request prevention?

Thanks for taking the time to read, any answers are appreciated.

Comment: Are you working with IIS?, if so, you can install the dynamic ip restrictions module: https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/dynamic-ip-restrictions

Comment: Currently it is deployed on an Azure server but I do a lot of testing on the local azure emulator before deploying

Comment: Also you need to implement something like, the `Valet Key Pattern` for your api endpoint